# Unable to fix lag issue on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: performance, driver, lag, ubuntu-13.10

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 last week and have since spent a few days trying to eliminate a lag issue with no success. Whenever a folder screen is dragged around the desktop there are massive amounts of lag. The computer is new and has 32 GB RAM. I have tried using Gnome, but there is still lag. I have tried to install the latest driver from the Dell website for this machine (3QBG022), but this seems not to have helped. I have tried the options described in the 'Fix for poor lagging desktop graphics performance in Ubuntu' youtube video that suggest downloading 'Compiz config manager' and deslecting the 'Sync to vblank' option- this did not work either. I have since installed Ubuntu 13.10, but the issue remains.

Computer details: 32 GB RAM, 
Processor: Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E3-1240 V2 @ 3.40GHz × 8 
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.3, 256 bits)
OS type: 64 bit
Disk: 7.9 TB

Could anyone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to know where it is spending time, profile it with "sudo perf record -a" and "sudo perf report".

Comment: Running top might help

Answer (score 0):

Try the workarounds mentioned in this thread:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1386721

Install the latest Gnome (May have bugs):

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/how-to-install-gnome-314-in-ubuntu.html

== TLDR: ==

-- Workarounds on boot:

```
sudo xdiagnose - check all workaround boxes
```

-- Install the latest Gnome (May have bugs):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and reboot!

See links for more details

Answer (score 0):

For a quick 'n dirty fix, install the Ublock Origin plugin in your browser, along with Privacy Badger.

I did and now Youtube runs smoothly on my 11-year old Inspion 1300 Dell laptop with a Celeron M 1.5Ghz 370 CPU and Lubuntu 14.04. Since the graphics card is only 8MB, I cannot view HD without lag. But that's a hardware issue.

I also tested this on a Dell Inspiron 6000, which is around 10 years old. Youtube playback was choppy and lagging here, also. Sound was fine, but video playback lagged horribly, with jumps and delay. After installing Ublock Origin and Privacy Badger plugins (in Firefox), Youtube playback was normal. Also running Lubuntu 14.04. I have tested the same procedure on Lubuntu 15.04, too. Same result.